# use PC simultaneously as Linux web-server while allowing Chrome Remote Desktop into Windows 11

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, windows-11, webserver

I have an "alder lake" (ultra low power-consumption Intel chip) [mini PC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MCZ6NDG).

It comes with Windows 11. This is a "headless" PC, designed to be plugged into the internet, and accessed remotely. It has 16gb RAM and a 512gb SSD.

What I'd like to do is, **simultaneously**:

1. Run a Linux-based web-server (accessible from the internet) on it (for development and testing of a website idea I have, and for practicing Linux-server skills).
2. Be able to use Chrome Remote Desktop to access Windows 11 on it.
3. (**not as important**) Run some sort of [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/)-type media server on it. This would be on the Linux side of things, and would use a different port than the webserver.

I've figured out how to do port-forwarding, for different ports, on my home internet connection.

My **one** question is: how can I have "constantly on" Linux and Windows 11 simultaneously on the same box? (Let's say say port 80 goes to the Linux webserver, and there's a different port [say, 3389] for Remote Desktop into Windows)?

Comment: You cannot have two OSes simultaneously running at the "root" level on any computer. You can virtualize, but I wonder if a NUC has the power necessary to do that well. What research have you done and what have you tried so far? Also, please note that we allow only one question per post. You can have more than one post, definitely, but this site is designed around single questions getting single answers. Please edit your post to fix these points and to add details.

Comment: @music2myear Surprisingly NUCs have the power and this one in particular has it and then some more. Enough RAM is more important here. That said, I'm writing this in Deepin Linux in an unbranded "NUC" (Celeron 3965U) with only 4GB of RAM while virtualizing Windows 10 (1.5GB RAM assigned).

Comment: @ChanganAuto the box has 16gb RAM and a 512gb SSD.

Comment: So it can run a Linux VM perfectly. WSL/WSL2 is also an option. There's really nothing else we can tell you for this question. If you were familiar with the virtualization concept you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. I'm somewhat familiar with virtualization. I'll research how to expose port 80 from the virtualized Linux or WSL to the wider internet. So that the webserver can run inside virtualized Linux/WSL (which would be inside Windows 11), and still be accessible from the internet. Thanks again.

Comment: @thanks_in_advance the combination `exposed to the internet` and `practicing linux-skills` sounds like **there be dragons**.

Comment: @tink LOL. Sometimes, you have to birth demons to learn to fight them.

Answer (score -1):

music2myear correctly pointed out that you can't have two OSes running at the same time.

However, windows has for some time had WSL/WSL2 available, and for a "training exercise" you should be able to run e.g. nginx under that - just don't get your hopes up performance-wise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1195290)

Comment: That's debatable @JoepvanSteen . The original request is unachievable (can't run Linux & Windows as the primary OS at the same time on the same hardware), WSL using nginx addresses the expressed use case.

Comment: It reads like a comment plus it is virtually a link only answer.

Comment: So if I added a WSL2 walk-through for Windows 11 it would have made it an answer? :) Get a break @JoepvanSteen  ... if all the potential answers (or the fact that it can't be answered) were just in comments might as well have the question expunged - otherwise comments are just a means of turning a Q&A site into a forum ...

Comment: You're turning this the wrong way around. I am not suggesting you take it comments, I am suggesting you posted a comment where you instead should have provided an answer. In essence what you posted is a comment/link only answer. I was asked to review and I did.